# accessing data from websql

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good Morning, I have a script that retrieves data from a WebSQL db, it works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
var v= location.search.replace("?init=", "");
document.getElementById('key').innerHTML=v;

var db = openDatabase('contacts', '1.0', 'contacts database', 5 * 1024 * 1024); var x = v + "%";    
 db.transaction(function(tx){   
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM names WHERE  lname  LIKE "' + x +'"', [], function (tx, results){  
  var len = results.rows.length, i;
  if(len > 1 ){   // if len is greater than 1 
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        $('#nameList').append("<li data-url='autolkp.html?id='" + results.rows.item(i).lname + "' class='n' id='"+results.rows.item(i).lname+"'>" + results.rows.item(i).lname + "</li>");
  }
  } // closes if len is greater than 1
else {  
        $("#fName").val(results.rows.item(0).fname);    
        $("#lName").val(results.rows.item(0).lname);
        $("#adx").val(results.rows.item(0).adx);
        $("#city").val(results.rows.item(0).city);
        $("#state").val(results.rows.item(0).st);
        $("#zip").val(results.rows.item(0).zip);
        $("#phone1").val(results.rows.item(0).phone1);
        $("#phone2").val(results.rows.item(0).phone2);
        $("#email").val(results.rows.item(0).email);
}   });   });  });
```

this script takes the results from the query and creates a list with the last names.

I am trying to access the data-url  from the li with this script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('li').click(function(){
    a = $(this).attr('data-url');
    alert(a);
}); });
```

it isn't working.  when you do a view page source - none of the data from the executeSql is visible, but when you go into console it is. Is this a timing issue?  How can I get around it?

Thx.

Comment: Please format your code readably when asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the `<li>` click listener before it renders the results. You just need to change the click listener to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#nameList').on('click', 'li', function() {
    // DO SOMETHING
  });
});
```